# Jquery on ready .val not working select

Tags: jquery, select, document-ready

Im filling a 'select' with multiple options with JSON/AJAX javascript and inside "document ready"..
Right after i will set the value of the select with:

```
$('#dropdown').val('99');
```

Nothing happens, but the function works fine if i place it in the console?

Comment: `$(document).ready` doesn't guarantee that your JSON/AJAX values are loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to place `$('#dropdown').val('99');` in the `success` callback of `.ajax`.

e.g.,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'google.com',
    success: function(){
        $('#dropdown').val('99');
    }
});
```

`$.ajax` is asynchronous, meaning any code directly after it will run *before* the ajax request is complete. It's likely you're trying to set the value to `99` before it's in the dropdown.

Comment: Ahh ofc. Ajax is asynchronous. TY